# How do I handle a thin strip of vinyl plank flooring against a wall?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I am removing carpet and putting in vinyl plank flooring.

I have finished the living room and am moving onto the family room. These two rooms are connected through a passage and separated by a wall in between. I got to the point where I need to install flooring along the edge of the wall of the second room and I need a strip about 3/4" wide to keep the flow. I am not removing the baseboard, but I do plan on installing shoe molding once done.

- Are there are risks with installing a 3/4" strip of flooring?
- If so, how do I mitigate the risks without undoing everything that's done so far?

There is a gap between baseboard and floor and it's large enough in some areas to slide the flooring underneath, should I consider that?

[image: Flooring picture]

Comment: you're not supposed to use anything less than a half-width plank. That small amount should have been deducted from the starting leading edge instead of starting with full-width. Live and learn. I doubt it's worth re-doing though. If there's no foot traffic, it will likely be ok. The concern is popout. You might glue the shim to the attaching plank, so that it "rides" with the last full-width row. You might also remove and back-cut the baseboard to allow a wider run. You can also use slightly thicker base/shoe to cover up the gap without ripping planks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like your idea of glueing. I probably going to do that.

Comment: it could be hard to get a good click with a narrow rip, and some designs will tend to lift up without the weight of a full plank. just a few drops of superglue on the tongue, weighted while "drying" will ensure it stays put yet still floats.

Comment: Thanks for more tips. I really like the idea of glueing down and waiting for it to dry.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern vinyl flooring locks together securely, and since you're putting down shoe I'd have no concerns--if the plank can't lift it can't come loose. I recently did my laundry room and had this same issue for part of a wall. It's not always possible to plan away such scenarios. My flooring has no problems.

Don't do anything hacky like larger moldings. That'll look lazy and amateurish. Just stick to the recipe and take care to get as good a bond as possible.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Do you think added little glue to tongue before locking would provide additional strength.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your flooring product, so I have no idea. I will hint that glue over any self-sealing material already on the flooring edge will not accomplish anything. If it's raw wood or fiber, sure.

Comment: It's coretec LVP. The tongue itself looks like MDF material. I'll test glueing small pieces together and see how it reacts. Thanks a lot for your responses. It's very helpful.